# Limit user submission to one per user with custom response Contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm working on a multilingual contest website, in which users are only allowed to signup once. I'm using [contact form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) with [CFDB plugin](https://cfdbplugin.com/). Using the below code provided by CFDB author, This function checks if the form is already submitted;

```
function is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $fieldValue) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBFormIterator.php');
    $exp = new CFDBFormIterator();
    $atts = array();
    $atts['show'] = $fieldName;
    $atts['filter'] = "$fieldName=$fieldValue";
    $atts['unbuffered'] = 'true';
    $exp->export($formName, $atts);
    $found = false;
    while ($row = $exp->nextRow()) {
        $found = true;
    }
    return $found;
}
```

along with the following code that validates the form, making sure there is no duplicate email (which is how i intend to detect duplicate users)

```
function one_user_per_contest($result, $tag) {
    $formName = array('Contest Form', 'Contest form ES'); // This is the form name for English and spanish
    $fieldName = 'your-email'; // Name of the field to validate, which is the email field
    $errorMessage = "you've signed up already"; // error message
    $name = $tag->name;
    if ($name == $fieldName) {
        if (is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $_POST[$name])) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, $errorMessage);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'one_user_per_contest', 20, 2);
```

This validation work fine, as it doesnt allow duplicate email but the issue i'm facing which i will like to get some direction on is that i want the error message to be displayed as a response. intead of the response saying `One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.`, i want it to say `you've signed up already` [see image below];

[image: Custom Response Result]

Thanks

Comment: Where does the string 'One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.' come from, exactly? Did you search for it? Ah probably from contact form 7 validation..
The hack would be to replace the string with JavaScript :-/

Comment: Did you check, if your one_user_per_contest() function is called, and if the first and second if are reached?

Comment: The function invalidate passes `invalidate->invalid_fields` array with 'reason' as a key.  See contact-form-7/includes/validation.php

Comment: @jasie The "One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again." is CF7 'Validation errors occurred' default message and yes the one_user_per_contest() function works, just not showing the message as response (which is what i want to achieve )

Comment: @HowardE In this example, the $tag is needed to prevent the form from sending. i'm not sure how to write this in array after checking the  contact-form-7/includes/validation.php line 7 (i.e. the public function __construct line)

Comment: It might be easier to write your own ajax validate function and use it instead of the CF7 function.

Comment: A snippet (however small, i can easily build off from there) would be so much appreciated as i'm new to ajax and php @HowardE

Comment: Hey I was thinking... have you tried making a contact form with only the fields you need, and make sure that recaptcha is turned off.  I feel like the error you're getting 
 might not be from your field.

Comment: The error I'm getting is the correct error, just want to overwrite it to say you've signed up already ... When the form detects duplicate email

Comment: hey did you find any solution to this error?

Comment: @sumanbiswas Based on the question. I remember the project now and what I did was build my own contact form with my validations exactly how I wanted it, connecting it to a CPT ( Custom Post Type ) that stores all User's inputs  (which was why I needed CFDB in the first place). I didn't later use CF7 and CFDB plugin. My PHP is sound now, so I might look at this issue again and come up with a solution